# How do I cancel cloning a Git repository from Git Bash?

Tags: git, git-bash, git-clone

I am currently using Git Bash to clone a large repository that has over 100,000 commits. The cloning process has been going on for over half an hour, and it still hasn't finished receiving objects.

**Is it possible to cancel a `git clone` command from Git Bash?**

(For reference, I am using Git 2.17.0 (64 bit) on Windows 7 Professional).

Comment: Press `Ctrl+C`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> should send a SIGINT or similar (signal for graceful exit) to the git process; if this does not help you can issue a SIGQUIT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>; last but not least you can always kill the process using the Windows Task Manager.

The directory you're cloning into may not be in a consistent state as a result of killing the git executable so you may wish to delete it before attempting to clone again, if git doesn't do so for you. When you try again, you can use the flag `--depth=N` to fetch only the last N commits.

Comment: On Unix-ish systems, control-C sends SIGINT. Does Windows really send SIGTERM? That's rather unfriendly...

Comment: @torek Apologies, this was a typo on my part that I've since corrected. Git Bash on Windows behaves sufficiently close to real Bach on "real" Linux/Unix as to have similar behavior.

Comment: Ah, OK. Note that if `git clone` gets interrupted it should clean up after itself and not leave an inconsistent-state partial clone, but if you use stronger kill methods, it may not be able to do so.